# How to retrieve current page WP_Query arguments?

Tags: wp-query, loop, shortcode

## Context

I'm developping a plugin showing geolocated posts on a leaflet map. **I want to add a shortcode parameter to show a map with only the current loop posts' markers.** That feature would be great on the search result page for exemple!

## Question

**Is there a way to get the current page WP_Query arguments?** I want to get those arguments to create a new WP_Query and add some more to filter only geolocated posts.

I don't know if it's possible at all, I always create new WP_query objects from scratch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using `$wp_query` ?

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

For a single variable, you can use [get_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)

Or you could try just dumping the `$_POST` , `var_dump( $_POST );`

Or maybe `var_dump( $GLOBALS['post'] );`

Comment: `$wp_query->query_vars` is exactly what I asked for :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `rewind_posts()` to get the posts from the current query, then amend from there:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rewind_posts/

This article has a good explanation of `rewind_posts()`, differentiating it from `wp_reset_postdata()` and `wp_reset_query()` : https://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it was not exactly what I was looking for (I was searching for current WP_query **arguments**)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to get it from the `query` args directly. You can access all of the `$args` this way.

```php
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// paged
$paged_arg = $query->query['paged'];
```